# Let $b>a>0$ , prove $\int_a^b\ln(x)\leq\frac{b^2-a^2}{2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I'm confused about this question and I don't know how to achieve this equation.

**My try :**
I tried using MVT for integrals so $$\int_a^b\ln(x)=f(c)(b-a)$$ for some $c\in[a,b]$.
maximum value for $\ln(x)$ in $[a,b]$ is $\ln(b)$ so $$\int_a^b\ln(x)=\ln(b)(b-a)<b(b-a)=b^2-ba.$$
this is the far I got.

I tried using the previous function using $F(x)=x\ln(x)-x$ such that $F`(x)=\ln(x)$, $F(x)$ is continuous then it's integrable so $$\int_a^b\ln(x)=b\ln(b)-b-a\ln(a)+a$$

Is there something I'm missing? any clues?
Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Comment: Can you show that $\ln x < x$ for all $x > 0$? Now what does that give you?

Comment: If $0<a<b$, we have $a^2<ab$, so $b^2-ab<b^2-a^2$.

Comment: @StephenDonovan , I used this inequality in the step $ln(b)(b-a) < b(b-a)$

Comment: @Yassir You seem to think $\ln x$ integrates to $1/x$, which is actually its derivative. The antiderivatives are of the form $x\ln x-x+C$.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I got confused. @J.G.

Comment: @Bernard wow how did I miss that , Now I need to think about $\frac {b^2-a^2}{2}$ tho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My process for proving this would be as follows.

To start, let's quickly prove that $\ln x < x$ for all $x > 0.$ We can do this by first showing this for all $0 < x \leq 1,$ then all $x > 1.$

If $0 < x \leq 1,$ then by the monotonicity of the natural log we have $\ln x \leq 0,$ and because $0 < x$ we have $\ln x < x.$

If $x > 1,$ then consider the function $f(x) = x - \ln x.$ Its derivative, $f'(x) = 1 - \frac1{x}$ is strictly positive for $x > 1.$ So, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing for $x > 1,$ and because $f(1) = 1, f(x) > 1$ for all $x > 1.$

---

Now let's use this to prove our desired statement. If $f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b],$ then $\int_a^b f(x) dx \leq \int_a^b g(x) dx.$

So, $\ln x \leq x$ on the region $[a,b]$ for any $0 < a < b$ implies that $\int_a^b \ln x dx \leq \int_a^b x dx = \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2},$ which is our desired statement.

Comment: I knew that inequality and also used it yet you found a better and simpler use for that! +1 Thank you.

Comment: No problem, have a nice day